# multipart/form-data http post request curl vc++

Tags: visual-c++, curl

first time curl user, working on a curl fileupload with http `multipart/form-data` request with vc++.

After researching I found two ways to make a `multipart/form-data` request. Either use "`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`" set a value as an array or use formadd and pass the pointer to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. I decided to do the second and configure the different fields of the request with "formdata" (two fields, one file (application/sla) the other one origin (text/plain)

I used wireshark to catch the request and saw that CURL returned `CURLE_READ_ERROR (26)`. Then I added CURLFORM_FILECONTENT, "tmp_3DButton.stl" and got CURL_OK but the server I was sending the request to returned "Bad Media Type" and I saw that CURL didnt send my request as multipart..

(win8 64 bit, visual studio 2015, curl, c++

```
                    CURL *curl;
                    CURLcode res;
                    char error[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];

                    struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
                    struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;
                    struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;

                    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

                    // Fill in the file upload field 
                    curl_formadd(&formpost,
                        &lastptr,
                        CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "file",
                        CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "application/sla", 
                        CURLFORM_FILECONTENT, "tmp.stl",
                        CURLFORM_FILE, filePathSTL, 
                        CURLFORM_END);

                    // Fill in the filename field 
                    curl_formadd(&formpost,
                        &lastptr,
                        CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "origin",
                        CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "text/plain",
                        CURLFORM_FILENAME, "se_1_0",
                        CURLFORM_END);

                    curl = curl_easy_init();


                    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Accept: text/plain");



                    if (curl) {
                        // URL that receives this POST 
                        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://blabla.com/upload");

                        //multipart/form-data
                        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
                        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);


                        2);
                        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, error);


                        error[0] = 0;
                        // Perform the request, res will get the return code 
                        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

                        CString str;
                        // Check for errors 
                        if (res != CURLE_OK)
                        {
                            str.Format("curl_easy_perform return %s [%d]", curl_easy_strerror(res), res);
                            size_t len = strlen(error);
                            if (len) 
                            {
                                _bstr_t bstrt(error);
                                AfxMessageBox(error);
                            }
                        }

                        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

filePathSTL is bstrt for example `C:\..\..\tmp.stl` (with doubled slashes..)

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, "CURLFORM_FILE" obviously wants a string!